# Dragon Quest Builders 2

Tags: dragon-quest-builders-2

Does anyone know when you  do free play or creative in Dragon Quest Builders 2? Instead of doing quests
I have already beat Furrowfield and the Detire Tree

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I have played it so I apologise if any of the terminology is off...

Basically, there is no "creative mode". The closest to this that you get is your "home island" (I forget what it is called). Here you can complete the tablet quests to earn rewards that improve your ability to build on the home island by gaining extra tools, this will typically require you to complete the game to unlock all of these though.

Your home island eventually becomes your free-roam post-game content.

But if you are looking for a mode where you get unlimited blocks/materials, then this doesn't exist in this game.